# Simulate WebRTC Brower using node.js

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, webrtc

My question is kinda complex, so I think it's best to tell what I'm trying to accomplish.

My job is testing a telecommunication application. The app has a browser interface, the user can connect their phone extension to it, make and receive calls through the browser.

To test, we have a node.js Tool, that simulates the browser, sending and receiving the requests from the server instead of the browser interface. It works perfectly.

My problem is that the application also can work with WebRTC. In this case it's the browser who take care of the call, not the "physical" phone extension. SO I would need to implement the WebRTC in the test tool. How can I do that?

Most things I find in the web is to implement the server side on Node.js, while leaving the browser side, to well, the browser. But that is the part I need.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to do the same thing. You can use the npm package called `wrtc` in node. But in my case, I need to access the simulated browser's window object and emulate a browser's audio devices in node.js. I tried using `puppeteer` but to no avail. Using `mock-browser` I got further, but I couldn't emulate audio devices with that library :(

Answer (score 1):

you can enable webrtc on your node js test tool just by installing webrtc package on your node js as below

```
npm install wrtc
```

follow below link if you want to understand apis and other functionalities
[node-webrtc](https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc)